# calling action method from Jquery and redirecting the user to an external site

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I would like to call the mvc controller action method from jQuery, and when the action method gets invoked, the user should be transferred to another site. I have tried using jquery ajax to do this but after response.redirect, my page still stays on the same URL with out any change.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        success: function (Data) {
        //don't want to use this callback as I require only calling the 
        action method
        }
    });
```

and in the controller

```
public void Action(){
  // process the request and redirect
    Response.Redirect("url", false);
 }
```

Can anyone help me in understanding where the issue is in the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `window.location.href = Data` ?

Comment: you can use `window.location.href` into your success method .you can redirect to anywhere by using this.

Comment: I think this will worl for you return Redirect("http://www.google.com");

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

or try using javascript

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 return Content("<script>window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
 </script>");
}
```

You can check this link to know about Redirect vs RedirectResult

[return new RedirectResult() vs return Redirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875894/return-new-redirectresult-vs-return-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it is working. I hope this helps :-)

**HTML**

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="RedirectTosite()">Redirect To Google</button>
```

**Jquery Call**

```
function RedirectTosite() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Employee/RedirectTosite',
        success: function (Data)
        {
            window.location = Data;              
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public JsonResult RedirectTosite()
    {
        return Json("http://www.google.com", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get a clue why are you calling server using ajax if you don't do any data manipulation on the database if you are aiming just to redirect to a page simply redirect using javascript code like

```
window.location.href = '/Controller/Action/'
```

Ok I am convinced you have done some work on the void method, If you redirect page on the void method ajax request fails and you are not redirected to another page. For it to work you simply remove the line of code

```
    Response.Redirect("url", false);
```

from controller and write a line of code as follows inside success function of ajax .

```
window.location.href = '/Controller/Action/'
```